# Plotting a line that's first value is not at x = 0

Tags: matplotlib

I have several `ndarray`s that I would like to plot on the same graph.  Each is the same size.  The first contains y data for x=0, x=1, x=2, x=3.  The second contains y data for x=1,x=2,x=3,x=4.  And the third contains y data for x=2,x=3,x=4,x=5.

Is there anyway I can get Pyplot to shift the line over 1, so that they all appear starting at their appropriate x values?

(I know I could just prepend one or two dummy values to the lines, but I don't want that, I want the line to start in the right place)

### UPDATE

To explain better, here is the data:

```
x |y1 |y2 |y3
-------------
0 | 0 | - | -
1 | 1 | 0 | -
2 | 2 | 1 | 0
3 | 3 | 2 | 1
4 | - | 3 | 2
5 | - | - | 3
```

That is, line y1 is defined starting at x=0, line y2 is defined starting at x=1, and line y3 is defined starting at x=2.  Likewise, y2 is defined for x=4 whereas y1 isn't.  (You can think of y2 as a translation to the right of y1).

Using plot, all lines start at the same x coordinate, which I don't want.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you explain better?

Comment: See my answer. If you have some way of keeping track of the offset for each `y`, you only need to have one `x` array, and can just say `plt.plot(x+offset,yi)`. If you want to totally omit `x`, that won't work according to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). If you only supply `y`, the x data will always be the indices of `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you just supply a range of x values for each y range to `plot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.arange(4)
x2 = x1+1
x3 = x2+1

for x in (x1,x2,x3):
    plt.plot(x,np.random.randint(10,size=4))

plt.show()
```